# Laravel model relationships approach

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a downside to connecting models with this syntax:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_permission');
```

Instead of standard string variant:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Admin\Model\Role', 'role_permission');
```

I prefer the first syntax for it's brevity, and also a nice feature to have with IDE's to recognize the class as a class, not a string.

Comment: no, the former just wasn't supported in previous versions of PHP.

Comment: technically the string is more 'explicit' but the class constant is the way to go these days, incase you move a class, you wont have to change that reference, only the alias .. models are usually in the same namespace so in these cases you dont even have to alias them, etc .. not an inclusive list